# Is there any reasonable proposal on multiplication of square matrices of different order?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix multiplication of square matrices of different order is often claimed to be impossible. Yet, if the order of one matrix is divisible by the order of the other, a natural multiplication rule is visible. The bigger matrix simply should be considered a "matrix of matrices" or, alternatively, in small matrix all elements should be replaced with equivalent diagonal $m\times m$ (in this case, $2\times2$) square matrices:

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_1} & {b_1} \\
 {c_1} & {d_1} \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_2} & {b_2} \\
 {c_2} & {d_2} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_3} & {b_3} \\
 {c_3} & {d_3} \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_4} & {b_4} \\
 {c_4} & {d_4} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & b & 0 \\
 0 & a & 0 & b \\
 c & 0 & d & 0 \\
 0 & c & 0 & d \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 {a_1} & {b_1} & {a_2} & {b_2} \\
 {c_1} & {d_1} & {c_2} & {d_2} \\
 {a_3} & {b_3} & {a_4} & {b_4} \\
 {c_3} & {d_3} & {c_4} & {d_4} \\
\end{array}
\right)$
$=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a {a_1}+{a_3} b & a {b_1}+b {b_3} \\
 a {c_1}+b {c_3} & a {d_1}+b {d_3} \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a {a_2}+{a_4} b & a {b_2}+b {b_4} \\
 a {c_2}+b {c_4} & a {d_2}+b {d_4} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_1} c+{a_3} d & {b_1} c+{b_3} d \\
 c {c_1}+{c_3} d & c {d_1}+d {d_3} \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_2} c+{a_4} d & {b_2} c+{b_4} d \\
 c {c_2}+{c_4} d & c {d_2}+d {d_4} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$
$=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a \text{a1}+\text{a3} b & a \text{b1}+b \text{b3} & a \text{a2}+\text{a4} b & a \text{b2}+b \text{b4} \\
 a \text{c1}+b \text{c3} & a \text{d1}+b \text{d3} & a \text{c2}+b \text{c4} & a \text{d2}+b \text{d4} \\
 \text{a1} c+\text{a3} d & \text{b1} c+\text{b3} d & \text{a2} c+\text{a4} d & \text{b2} c+\text{b4} d \\
 c \text{c1}+\text{c3} d & c \text{d1}+d \text{d3} & c \text{c2}+\text{c4} d & c \text{d2}+d \text{d4} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

So, in certain circumstances this is possible. Thus, my question is: can this somehow be generalized to the matrices of orders that are not divisors of each other? Possibly, the resulting matrix would be of the order which is the least common multiple of the orders of the terms?

Comment: We can define all sorts of things... To my mind, the question is what _properties_ we expect/require a thing to have... not just a formulaic definition. Can you clarify?

Comment: In case it helps, what you describe above is basically tensor multiplication.

Comment: @paulgarrett my primary aim was to see how this definition of matrix multiplication (of different orders) can be generalized to empty matrix (which is unclear whether can be done at all).

Comment: You can put all the square matrices on the diagonal of a larger matrix.

Comment: @JosephCamacho thanks, I did not know about this. I've seen a video on youtube about tensor multiplication, and it looked like something different. Can we use tensor multiplication in regards of an empty matrix?

Comment: As @JosephCamacho comments, what you write is basically a tensor multiplication. But "empty matrix" does not fit so well into that...

Comment: @paulgarrett my hypothesis which I explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483012/is-it-consistent-to-represent-empty-matrix-as-infty?noredirect=1#comment9401141_4483012 is that an empty matrix simply naturally should be considered equal to $\infty$. Thus, it can be represented as a diagonal matrix of any order with elements from $\overline{\mathbb R}$

Comment: Multiplication on a set $X$ is a map $X\times X\to X$. What you have defined is different, it is a map of the form $X\times Y\to Y.$ What you have defined is some sort of action of 2 by 2 matrices on 4 by 4 matrices. Although I am not sure whether it has any nice properties, and your choice of the order in some of the product puzzles me. For example, I guess you don't have $(A\cdot B)\cdot C=A\cdot(B\cdot C).$

Comment: @SergeyGuminov I think it is consistent because the original matrix can be represented as $4\times4$ matrix without losing isomorfism. So, it is basically the same as multiplying two $4\times4$ matrices.

Comment: @Anixx It is very, very far from being the same.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov the first matrix is equivalent to $\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & b & 0 \\
 0 & a & 0 & b \\
 c & 0 & d & 0 \\
 0 & c & 0 & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: @JosephCamacho for some reason, Mathematica evaluates tensor product differenty...

Comment: @SergeyGuminov Let $X=\bigcup_{n∈ℕ, m∈ℕ} ℝ^{n×m}$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and made a Mathematica code for this kind of multiplication. The code below can multiply square matrices of ANY order (except $0$).

```
DotG[A_, B_] := 
 KroneckerProduct[A, 
   IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[A]]] . 
  KroneckerProduct[B, 
   IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[B]]]
```

This multiplication is associative and generalizes the dot product of matrices of the same order.